# I would like to move a UIButton to a specific location, like on a grid

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

Aloha everyone,
  I have a background image with a grid layout and would like to allow the user to move one of a set of buttons to specific grid locations, but only to those specific locations. In other words, say I wanted to limit the movement on the y axis to increments of, say 65 pixels, then snap the button to the closest point (if you moved it 67 pixels, it would snap back 2 pixels).  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is the question 1) how to let a user drag elements or 2) how to move buttons once you know destination coords or 3) how to round coords to the nearest number on a grid or 4) all three of the above?

Comment: Aloha ckhan, in answer to your questions, I would can drag the buttons, but would like to impose certain moves on specific buttons.  In other words, the buttons have to move in a specific pattern.  I can figure out the coords (by specifying x and y distance), but need to limit the button to only moving to specific coords in a specific pattern.  The user should be able to move the button to that specific coord, but have the button snap back it the button is moved to an incorrect coord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code I'm currently working with, it allows the user to drag and drop an image around the screen. You'll notice the "if" statements with values set to "960" and "640" and such, this states that if the user attempts to drag the image off screen it animates the image moving back into the screen and can be easily modified to make the image move to the closest grid coordinate that the user dropped in near.

```
- (void)callMarkerFourteen
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VerticalLine.png"];

    markerViewFourteen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 210, 40, image.size.height)];
    [markerViewFourteen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5]];
    markerImageViewFourteen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[markerViewFourteen frame]];
    [markerImageViewFourteen setFrame:CGRectMake(18, 0, 4, 100)];
    [markerImageViewFourteen setImage:image];
    [markerViewFourteen addSubview:markerImageViewFourteen];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [markerViewFourteen addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    [self.view addSubview:markerViewFourteen];
}


-(void)move:(id)sender {

    [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (0.0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
        CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (0.0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

            if(finalX < 0) {                                
                finalX = 0;             
            }                           
            else if(finalX > 640) {

                finalX = 640;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {                                
                finalY = 0;             
            }                       
            else if(finalY > 960) {

                finalY = 960;
            }
        }

        else {

            if(finalX < 0) {                                
                finalX = 0;             
            }                       
            else if(finalX > 960) {

                finalX = 640;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {                                
                finalY = 0;             
            }                       
            else if(finalY > 640) {

                finalY = 960;
            }
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: Aloha MDT, thank you for your response.  I'll take a good look at it and figure out how to modify it for my purposes.